# store value & then add on next search jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to store the value of searched result locally & then add in existing result.

```
function filterProd(filter) {
    var f = ".f_" + filter;
    if ($.inArray(f, filters) > -1) filters = $.grep(filters, function (val) {
        return val != f;
    });
    else filters.push(f);

    if (filters.length == 0) {
        $(".f_all").show(); // show all products
        $("#filtered").hide(); // hide reset button
        return;
    } else {
        $("#filtered").show(); // show reset button
    }

    $(".f_all").hide(); // first hide all products
    $(filters.join("")).show(); // show products only for this category
}
```

want to do union in place of interception.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuldeep/tLQFp/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is change this

```
$(filters.join("")).show();
```

to

```
$(filters.join(",")).show();
```

This way instead of `.class1.class2.class3...` you get `.class1,.class2...`

Comment: Hi James,
One more question quick one, if you can see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuldeep/tLQFp/3/), there are 3 columns & as suggested by you i had added ($(filters.join(",")).show();). Now it is doing union in columns & rows also. I want to do interception in column & union in rows.

Comment: That is considerably more difficult.  You will need to keep track of each category's filters separately and probably chain `.filter`s